# Finding how many zeroes $2z^3-3z^2+15$ has in $\pi/4>\arg(z)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Consider the polynomial $2z^3-3z^2+15$.

I have proved that this polynomial has one unique zero in the first quadrant. Now I am asked to see how many zeroes this polynomial has in the first half of the first quadrant (the region where $\pi/4>\arg(z)>0$).

I have tried to use contour integration and then the principal argument without succeeding.

Comment: not using contour integration, one notes that $2(1.5)^3+3(1.5)^2<15$ so the real root $r$ satisfies $r < -1.5$ so $r^2 >9/4$ while $r^2+z_1^2+z_2^2=9/4$ so $z_1, z_2=\bar z_1$ satisfy $|\Re z_{1,2}| < |\Im z_{1,2}|$ which means the answer is $0$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you try the principal argument, but you can try this maybe.

The principal argument say that $$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} dz = N $$ where $N$ is the amount of zeros that is within the region delimited by
$\gamma$, if $f$ is meromorphic (what you function is) and if it doesn´t have polos o zeros in $\Omega$.

I encourage you to try with the following curve.

[image]

We can make this curve in three steps.

$\gamma_1(t)=t(1+i) $ where $t \in [R,0]$ (in that order so it goes down), then

$\gamma_2(t)= t $ where $t \in [0,R]$ and finally

$\gamma_3(t)=Re^{it}$ where $t\ \in [0, \pi/4]$

Then if you make the limits when $R$ tends to $\infty$ you obtain the domain you want.